# can't read inside of txt file with batch file

Tags: batch-file

after writing IP inside txt using PowerShell, I can't read it with batch file

inside txt file

```
122.237.121.26
```

```
$Line = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://ipinfo.io" | select-object -property ip
($Line  |  Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.Value | Out-File -FilePath C:\src\Newfolder\currentip.txt
```

```
For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("C:\src\Newfolder\currentip.txt") Do Set "k=%%G"
echo %k%
pause
```

but if I manually create "currentip.txt" and put ip inside it manually, then run this command

```
For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("C:\src\Newfolder\currentip.txt") Do Set "k=%%G"
echo %k%
pause
```

I get output, but if I use PowerShell I got this messege

```
C:\src\Newfolder>For /F UseBackQ Delims= EOL= %G In ("C:\src\Newfolder\currentip.txt") Do Set "k=%G"

C:\src\Newfolder>echo
ECHO is on.

C:\src\Newfolder>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the txt file? Are they correct? Maybe include them in the question. Else maybe double check your Powershell code.

Comment: in txt file my ip 122.237.121.26 , or anything like 143

Comment: What is the batch command trying to do?

Comment: Check the coding of the text file written by PowerShell; is it ASCII/ANSI or some kind of Unicode?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$Line = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://ipinfo.io" | select-object -property ip
($Line  |  Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.Value | Out-File -FilePath C:\fruitlab\temp\currentip.txt -Encoding ascii
```

add

```
-Encoding ascii
```

so it Encoding ps output into ascii as batch reads ascii

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Code-only answers should be avoided. Could explain why this should work ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as if you've made this more complicated than it needs to be. You could try it without a holding text file, which would mean that the encoding of that file will not be a problem. Also I'm not sure what the purpose of  using a selection pattern against the returned `ip` is, as I presume it would always be returned in IPv4 format.

```sh
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 -NoProfile "(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri \"http://ipinfo.io\").ip" 2^>NUL'
) Do @Echo %%G
@Pause
```